# Trying to join two function returns in Angular.js or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular controller. I want to take items from both `x` and `y` variables and show them on the web page. Right now, the web page only shows items from the `y` variable. I try to use `.push()` to put the two function result sets together into the `PremByClass` array. Any help or direction on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
app.controller('PremByClass', ['$scope', '$http', 'policyApi', 'lookupApi', function ($scope, $http, policyApi, lookupApi) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.load.then(function () {
        function formatDate(value) {
            return value.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + value.getDate() + "-" + value.getFullYear();
        }
        $scope.PremByClass = [];
        policyApi.policy.get().then(function (t) {
            if (t) {
                policyApi.class.get().then(function (x) {
                    if (x) {
                        //Put x into $scope.PremByClass
                        $scope.PremByClass.push(x);
                        var dtEff = formatDate(t.DateEffective);
                        for (var i = 0, e = null; e = x[i]; i++) {
                            lookupApi.WCClassDesc.get(e.GovState, e.classCode, e.DescCode, dtEff).then(function (y) {
                                //This seems to wrok correctly however it seems that $scope.PremByClass forgets about x
                                //The web page only shows stuff from y
                                $scope.PremByClass.push(y);
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that your **x** variable is an array, I guess you should be showing it in your page as a list or table of objects with something like :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in PremByClass[0]">
    {{item.GovState}} // {{item.classCode}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I used the index 0 on PremByClass because your **x** variable is the first item you push into the PremByClass array. Although, I would make that part of the code more maintainable by setting the **x** variable into a more meaningful scope property.

You could replace this line in your controller:

```
$scope.PremByClass.push(x);
```

with this line:

```
$scope.policies = x;
```

and then simply rewrite your ng-repeat block to use **policies**:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in policies">
    {{item.GovState}} // {{item.classCode}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

the variable/array PremByClass would then contain only results from your **lookupApi.WCClassDesc** service or factory and you should be able to render them on screen using the same ng-repeat code as above simply replacing **policies** with **PremByClass**.